# How can I create a raster from my data in order to extract data using a shapefile in R?

Tags: r, raster, mask, shapefile

I have a netcdf file that I read into R, perform some analysis and ultimately produce data in the list format below:

```
vap=array(1:100, c(1,451,351))

#create the list
Variable <- list(Data = vap)
xyCoords <- list(x = seq(from = -10.763300, to = -5.238170, by = 0.01578607), y = seq(from = 51.36150, to = 55.43160, by = 0.009044647))
Dates <- list(start = seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2005-01-02"), by="days"), end=seq(as.Date("2005-01-01"), as.Date("2005-01-02"), by="days"))
#All <- list(Variable = Variable, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
All <- list(Variable = Variable,Data=vap, xyCoords=xyCoords,Dates=Dates)
```

I want to cookie cut this data using a shapefile. I have a shapefile which
I changed the projection in (to match my original Netcdf file) using:

```
SHP <- readOGR("myshp.shp")
b <- raster("mynetcdf.nc")
SHP <- spTransform(SHP, crs(b))
```

What I want to do now, is cookie cut my list above. I can do this if my data is already in raster format. For example:

```
Masking <- mask(b, SHP)
```

However, I can't create the raster directly from the list above. I think I need to use rasterFromXYZ:

```
#drop the time variable
data<-drop(All$Data)
#copy the crs
copycrs<-b@crs
```

#get the data ready to create the raster

```
xyz <- cbind(x=rep(All$xyCoords$x, length(All$xyCoords$y)), rep(All$xyCoords$y, each=length(All$xyCoords$x)),data,crs=copycrs)
```

But I get this warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: In cbind2(argl[[i]], r) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
2: In cbind2(argl[[i]], r) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)
```

What's the best way to create the raster so I can cookie cut out data using my shapefile?